Retag request for questions about Atari 8-bit computers
It seems that most of the questions tagged here as atari-400 or atari-800 actually apply to multiple Atari 8-bit computer models.  I propose that we introduce an atari-8-bit tag for questions that apply generically to the 400/800/XL/XE family of computers, while reserving atari-400, atari-800, and atari-xl for more model-specific questions.
